# How did Flaubert show in Bouvard et Pécuchet that history repeats itself?

Tags: french-language, gustave-flaubert, bouvard-et-pecuchet

The French Wikipedia article on Gustave Flaubert contains a [section on *Bouvard et Pécuchet*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gustave_Flaubert&oldid=173555011#Bouvard_et_P%C3%A9cuchet), the author's unfinished novel. This section contains the following unsourced statement:

> Critiquant les idées reçues, Flaubert montre que, contrairement à ce que pense Hegel, l'Histoire n'a pas de fin, elle est un éternel recommencement<sup>[réf. souhaitée]</sup>.

Translation:

> Criticising received ideas, Flaubert shows that, contrary to what Hegel thought, History has no goal but eternally repeats itself.

The statement is not to be found in the French Wikipedia article about [*Bouvard et Pécuchet*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bouvard_et_P%C3%A9cuchet&oldid=172941290) nor in the corresponding articles [*Bouvard et Pécuchet* in the English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bouvard_et_P%C3%A9cuchet&oldid=915548694) and [*Bouvard und Pécuchet* in the German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bouvard_und_P%C3%A9cuchet&oldid=195870170) (let alone in the articles about the author).

Searching for instances of "histoire" in an [online version of *Bouvard et Pécuchet*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Bouvard_et_P%C3%A9cuchet) did not help either. Hence my question: did Flaubert really show that history repeats itself? If yes, how?